# SwiftUI + Firebase Reauthenticate Passwordless Signin Error

Tags: firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am getting an error when trying to reauthenticate a user in Firebase in order to update their email address. The account was set up with the [Email Authentication Method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth?authuser=1) that allows for passwordless sign in.

The error says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" and is in the line "let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail:email, link:link)" at the .credential part.

Function:

```
func updateUser(updateField: String, fieldValue: String) {
    
    if fieldValue != "" {
        if (updateField == "email") {
            Auth.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail(to: newEmail) { (error) in
              if error != nil {
                let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
                let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail:email, link:link)
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { authData, error in
                  if (error) {
                    // And error occurred during re-authentication.
                    return
                  }
                  // The user was successfully re-authenticated.
                }
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Body:

```
// MARK: - BODY
var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
            .frame(height: 50.0)
            .foregroundColor(Color.grey5)
        HStack {
            Text(placeholder)
                .font(Font.custom("Gotham-Medium", size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(.dsCharcoal)
            Spacer()
            
                TextField(placeholder, text: $text, onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
//                        print("Username onEditingChanged - \(changed)")
                }) {
                    updateUser(updateField: self.fieldType, fieldValue: self.text)
                } //: TEXT FIELD
                .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                .font(Font.custom("Gotham-Book", size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(.grey2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            
            
        } //: HSTACK
        .padding(.horizontal)
    } //: ZSTACK
    .padding(.horizontal)
    
}
```

I've tried several different versions of the code and all of them seem to error out in some way. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What link you are passing here ? let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail:email, link:link) it required string type link

Comment: You can also use this ```let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: "your_email", password: "your_pass")```

Comment: I'm guessing the link will be the dynamic link I set up that is used when a person initially signs in. That looks something like this "https://myappname.page.link/open". The account is set up using the password-less method, so there is no password to pass.

Comment: Okay. If I pass as string then it works fine

Comment: Just pass a static string and check

Comment: That error is now gone, however, when I test I get this error:  'The link provided is not valid for email/link sign-in. Please check the link by calling isSignInWithEmailLink:link: on Auth before attempting to use it for email/link sign-in.'

Comment: If I remove the code I have currently, and use the sendSignInLink method instead, that seems to work. Not sure if it's the best way to do this ... but it's a solution for the moment.  Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: email!, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings) { error in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            } else {
                                print("sent")
                            }
                        }